# Why is git pull not using .git-credentials when credential helper set to store for SSH remote repository

Tags: linux, git

I was trying to follow the git-credentials documentation on my Ubuntu machine (per https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential) to set up a test where a user decides to save credentials for their git repository instead of entering every time.  I'm trying to test a git plugin that is built on top of libgit2, but I can't even get my test environment using the normal git command line to work.  Personally I always use SSH credentials, but I want to test this scenario.

To prepare for this test, I set up a VM with an SSH server and an account that requires a password where my remote git repository is created.

On my client machine I did:
`git config --global credential.helper store`

Upon checking - That command updated my global ~/.gitconfig to have the following lines:

`... [credential] helper = store`

When I do the git pull command, it prompts for my password, I enter, it, but it never stores the credentials in ~/.git-credentials.

When I do the 'git pull' command again it just prompts again.

It is acting like there is something not "activated" for 'git pull' to use the credential store.

If I manually do 'git credential approve' it updates ~/.git-credentials, and when I do 'git credential fill' it retrieves the content but the 'git pull' command does not.

Clearly I'm missing something (most likely) or there is a bug (least likely).

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (i.e. jammy).  The git version is: 2.34.1

Most of the documentation about git credentials is for using HTTP, is SSH not supported?

I was expecting 'git pull' to initially prompt for and get the password for the ssh account used as the remote origin for this repository and then store it in ~/.git-credentials.  Upon a second use of 'git pull' I was expecting it to find the saved credentials in ~/.git-credentials and use them successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git credentials is only for HTTP(S). To use Git credentials switch your protocol to HTTPS: `git remote set-url origin https://user@host/path/to/repo` (the server must support HTTP access and authentication).

For SSH use public key authentication: create a keypair (using `ssh-keygen`), upload the public key to the server (for a regular Unix server use `ssh-copy-id`, for a Git hosting upload using web interface or API), test passwordless login using `ssh user@sever` (for a Git hosting use `ssh git@server`), test Git using `git ls-remote user@host:/pat/to/repo` .

Comment: Ok, thanks for the insight.  I will try to do a test with http.  I'll have to figure out how to host HTTP access, but that's a different issue.